# Ehcache and Tomcat 8 incompatibility?

Tags: java, ehcache, tomcat8

I have a webapp configured with a webfilter that uses ehcache. Everything worked fine until I upgraded to Tomcat 8.0.15. The following error prevents my app to start:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: null:7: Element <cache> does not allow attribute "maxBytesLocalDisk".
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler.setAttribute(BeanHandler.java:282)
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.BeanHandler.startElement(BeanHandler.java:113)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:155)
        ... 26 more
```

Here is my ehcache configuration:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<cache name="CachingRestFilter"
       maxBytesLocalHeap="100M"
       maxBytesLocalDisk="1G"           
       eternal="false"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
       <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>      
 </cache>
</ehcache>
```

The same app works with Tomcat 7.0.54. Is this an issue with Tomcat?

Comment: Can you give the Ehcache version you are using? Can you verify there is not an older ehcache jar in the classpath of Tomcat 8?

Comment: I tried with a vanilla Tomcat 8 in another environment and it worked. I still do not know why it doesn´t in the first one, even when copying the working Tomcat to it. At least, it is not an issue with Tomcat anyway.